# WCF and Java interoperability

Tags: java, wcf

What is supported out of the box with a Java Client talking to WCF service version 4.0.
What protocols, bindings and security features are not supported (limitations if any).

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on the capabilities of the Java SOAP toolkit you are using (Metro, etc). As long as the Java side support SOAP you should be able to use BasicHttpBinding no problem - you will be able to use Transport security and maybe TransportWithMessageCredential

If the Java toolkit supports WS-Security then you should be able to use WSHTTPBinding with message security.

There are not many toolkits that support WS-ReliableMessaging and WS-AtomicTransaction so you are unlikely to be able to use these

WCF can be used to expose a RESTful service and all Java needs then is the ability to use HTTP and XML/Json. For this you would use webHttpBinding

Answer (score 1):

WCF is a .NET framework for providing standards-compliant web services.  If your WCF service is exposed over Http as SOAP or REST then, as far as your Java code is concerned, it's just a regular web service.